# JodaTime DateTime, ISO8601 GMT date format

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I get the following format:

```
2015-01-31T00:00:00Z
```

(ISO8601 GMT date format)

Out of a DateTime object in joda time (java) ? Eg.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.now();
String str = // Get something like 2012-02-07T00:00:00Z
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: How is this not clear? He defined exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The JODA [Javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toString%28%29) indicates that `toString` for `DateTime` outputs the date in ISO8601. If you need to have all of the time fields zeroed out, do this:

```
final DateTime today = new DateTime().withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
System.out.println(today);
```

That will include milliseconds in the output string. To get rid of them you would need to use the formatter that @jgm suggests here.

If you want it to match the format you are asking for in this post (with the literal `Z` character) this would work:

```
System.out.println(today.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")));
```

If you need the value to be UTC, initialize it like this:

```
final DateTime today = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Should there be a second single quote after `:ss'Z"` ?

Comment: What happens if the string has an offset in it, i need to parse the string to get a date time without an offset ' DateTime today = new DateTime("2016-07-11T05:04:30-05:30");
        System.out.println(today.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")));'gives a result like this "2016-07-11T05:34:30" where the mins field is altered @petter kjelkenes

Comment: @spuder Yes. A single quote is missing in the answer after Z.

Answer (score 10):

@jgm
In the document, `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()` is described

> Returns a formatter that combines a full date and time, separated by a
>   'T' (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ).

but if you set the timezone, e.g.,

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();  
System.out.println(fmt.print(new DateTime().toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)));
```

it will ends in Z.

Comment: Or also: `fmt.print(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC))`

Answer (score 5):

use [ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html)

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

Comment: Note that ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime() ends in ZZ not Z.  There's a difference (ZZ prepends a colon).

Comment: Although it's absolutely not clear what exactly petter is asking about, your example differs from his example: It includes milliseconds in the output and uses the default time zone instead of UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
formatter.print(time);
```