# Saving date in GMT format using Joda-time - Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I collect Date from my Spring MVC/ Hibernate app using the following code:

```
String startMembershipDate = request.getParameter("startmembershipdate");
```

and I am using the following field definition for this field in my entity

```
@Column(name="MEMBERSHIP_DATE", nullable=false, unique=false)
private Date membershipDate;
```

So I was wondering if someone can please provide me with an example on how to convert the received date in the JSP to GMT format using Joda-time?

Also shall I change the field definition from Date to DateTime? Timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question how to convert between `Date` and `DateTime`: [Convert from java.util.date to JodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042587/convert-from-java-util-date-to-jodatime)

This question tells you how to get format the `DateTime` using GMT: [JodaTime DateTime, ISO8601 GMT date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752782/jodatime-datetime-iso8601-gmt-date-format)

You can change the field definition to `DateTime` if you need to. You just have to write a custom Hibernate mapper then. We do that here and it works well (especially since we save dates as `DECIMAL(16)` so we don't get stupid bugs because of odd SQL `DATE` implementations, driver bugs, ...).

`java.sql.Timestamp` is something else. It's derived from `java.util.Date` and only adds the notion of nano seconds - which introduces some new subtleties that you need to be aware of. In my code, I stay away from it.

But unless you have a good reason (like finding that you convert to `DateTime` all the time), leave it alone.

Comment: My reason is that I have an app that have users from different locations around the world each with their own timezone and time format, so after reading a lot of SO articles related to this matter I noted that everyone recommends unifying the date format saved on server to GMT format then formatting the view for each user depending on his/her local date format...Please correct me if I am following wrong approach here? I am not sure how to persist GMT in DB using Date but read that it is super easy with Joda

Comment: Ah. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834665/how-can-i-handle-time-zones-in-my-webapp

Comment: Additional info: Use UTC (not GMT) to store the data. You can get the value to save by calling `getMillis()`. When you want to display the data, use the millisecond value plus the target time zone.

Comment: I am sorry can you elaborate getMillis() part? Do you mean saving Date/ time in millis format in DB then retrieving it and converting it from millis to Date/time again to the user?

Comment: Yes. The milliseconds are always relative to UTC and independent of the time zone. That means if 10 people around the globe ask Java for `System.currentTimeMillis()` right now, we would all get the same number (well, yeah, more or less). When you create a `Date` from that, you mix the independent millis with the local time zone to get a local date. Internally, a timezone is simply an offset to UTC. So when the date is formatted, it will do `millis+timezone.offset` first.

Comment: And using the millis approach, I can still get DateTime to display the date in different formats also (ex. MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD...etc)...correct?

Comment: Final question, will I still need to write a customer Hibernate mapper to save/ retrieve Date/time in millis?

Comment: You need a hibernate mapper if you want to save only the millis in the database.

Comment: @MChan RE: display DateTime in different formats… Yes. Joda-Time offers standard ISO 8601 formats, other built-in formats, Locale-sensitive formats, and you can define your own formats. Search StackOverflow for "joda format" for many examples.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Your answer and comments are clear and enlightening, except… I don't understand your statement `Use UTC (not GMT) to store the data`. The only difference between the two (UTC & GMT) is leap-seconds. And both Java & Joda-Time ignore leap seconds, which mean they *really* use GMT despite their "UTC" labels. So to what are you referring?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You're right, for most practical purposes the two are the same. But some people mean "GMT" == GMT date format. Also, most documentation in Java itself prefers UTC. It's interesting to see that Joda-Time avoids the terms when it can (see the quick start guide and JavaDoc for DateTime). Anyone interested in the details of the distinction between UTC and GMT should have a look at the JavaDoc for `java.lang.Date`.